# How to enable reverse search in zsh?

Tags: zsh, command-history, vi

I recently switched to zsh (finally) and am loving it! So far one thing that I am missing is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to do incremental history search.
I have the history set up properly

```
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=10000
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
```

and I used `vi` key bindings

```
bindkey -v
```

But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does not work. It removes the line above the current line, which is not the behavior it should have in vim either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: btw a quick work-around is to use non-incremental search: `Ctrl`+`[` `/` ...

Comment: Ctrl-R is an `emacs` shortcut. To search backwards in `vi`, it's `?`, though in zsh's `vi` mode `/` and `?` are reversed as you generally want to search backwards.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you need to explicitly set it, even with `bindkey -v`. Use something like this:

```
bindkey -v
bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
```

Comment: perhaps `history-incremental-pattern-search-backward` is an alternative action to use in that context.

Comment: @maxschlepzig sorry what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @Ali, with the *-pattern-* versions you can use search-patterns (which style, i.e. globbing or regex (?) depends on other parts of your zsh-configuration) - like e.g. you can use the search-pattern `fo*bar` with `grep` to match 'fobar', 'foobar', 'fooobar' etc.

Comment: I was getting an error. Wrapping ^R in double quotes did it. `bindkey "^R" history-incremental-pattern-search-backward`

Comment: `bindkey -v` must precede `history-incremental-search-backward`

Comment: Is there a fuzzy search alternative?

Comment: In general, and for the OP, It is helpful to set the forward incremental search by adding a second line to `~/.zshrc`: `bindkey '^s' history-incremental-search-forward`; press Ctrl+s a couple times after starting your Ctrl+r backward search, and you'll start going forwards again through the results, preventing you from having to start over if you go past the desired command

Answer (score 10):

OMZ framework has `zsh-history-substring-search` plugin [pre-packaged](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/history-substring-search). Just enable & use; for example:

```
plugins=(git zsh-history-substring-search)
```

Answer (score 9):

`bindkey -e` also works and makes zsh behave more like bash. It restores other things that you may have been using like ctrl-A (beginning of line), ctrl-K (delete everything to the right of the cursor).

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks. It solves a couple of problems at once, in a clean way.

Comment: Just adding a comment to explain that this sets so-called "emacs mode" which provides a lot of these settings even to those like me who aren't into emacs.